# to all javascript gurus out there: why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, closures

Why does this code:

```
function answer(x) {
  function closure() {
    var x = x || 42;
    console.log(x);
  }
  closure();
}
foo();
```

always prints `42`?

The logic would be that something like `foo(31337)` would print `31337`, since in `closure` `x` would be `31337`, so `x || 42` would evaluate to `31337`. But this is not the case.

I just can't figure this out, so I'm posting this here in hope of receiving enlightenment from one of the true javascript gurus out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function answer(x) {
  function closure() {
    var x = x || 42;
    console.log(x);
  }
  closure();
}
answer(20);
```

inside closure your defining `x` as a local variable. This means it shadows the argument `x` from the answer function higher up the chain. Since you declared `x` with a var statement it defaults to `undefined`.

Then `x || 42` is `undefined || 42` which is 42.

The issue here is that your using the same name. If you did `x = x || 42` it would be `x  = 28 || 42` which sets x to 28.

The distinction is using the `var` statement to create a new function local variable named x. Once you've done that, there is no way to reference variables of the same name that are higher up the scope chain.

To clarify how the interpreter works. Something like this :

```
function() {
    var x = 52;
    foo();
    function foo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Gets converted into

```
function() {
    function foo() {

    }
    var x;
    x = 52;
    foo();
}
```

Comment: so you say that `var x = x || 42;` is the same thing as `var x; x = x || 42;`, which would imply that `var x = (...)` `x` is declared as a local variable before executing `(...)`?

Comment: @NeuronQ exactly. To clarify all `var` statements get hoisted upto the top of scope. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

`var x` in `var x = x || 42;` shadows the argument.
And since `var ...` is always parsed at the beginning of the function - i.e. before the assignment is executed, the outer x is never available in there.

Here's a better example:

```
(function(x) {
    (function() {
        alert(x);
        var x = 'inside';
    })();
})(123);
```

The execution order is basically:

- Define var `x` with value `undefined`
- Execute `alert(x)`
- Assign `'inside'` to `x`